# How to display the most frequently occurring letter and the number of matches using streams?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a method that creates a list of random English letters and counts how many times each letter appears in the list. How to display only the letter that occurs most often and how many times does this letter occur in this list?

```
public class StreamPractice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(mostFrequentlyOccurringLetter());
    }

    private static Map<String, Integer> mostFrequentlyOccurringLetter() {
        return new Random().ints(100, 65, 91)
                .mapToObj(i -> String.valueOf((char) i))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), value -> 1, Integer::sum));
    }

}
```

Comment: You already created a map with occurrence per character. Just stream the `entrySet`, sort by `Entry::getValue` and then `findFirst`.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to use `groupingBy`  and store the count of each letter in a map. Then just stream the entry set and use max to get the entry with the highest number.

```
Map<String, Long> occurrences = new Random().ints(100, 65, 91)
    .mapToObj(i -> String.valueOf((char) i))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting());   
Optional<Map.Entry<String, Long>> max = occurrences.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .max(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new Random().ints(100, 65, 91)
        .mapToObj(i -> String.valueOf((char) i))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), value -> 1, Integer::sum));
map.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.<String,Integer>comparingByValue().reversed()) 
        .findFirst();
```